# How can I fix this CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I followed [this article](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/) and it's working but half way. See image shots below.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]

Comment: Can you explain the issues you are having? Trying to decipher that from the images is hard to do.

Comment: Can you please have a read of the help that can be displayed when you ask a question (click on the yellow question mark on the right of the formatting toolbar in the Ask Question page). This will help you format your posts better as I've tried to do above. Also as Marc says, please be specific when you ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

The Content Editor Webpart (CEWP) in 2010 does not allow scripts, it modifies the HTML when saved/edited. I faced this issue recently.

Rather that using HTML source of CEWP, use the option to link it to external file, create a text file in any document library and link the CEWP to it.

Now re write (do not copy from HTML source of CEWP) the HTML and script, it should work fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I have been doing. I saved everything in txt file and giving reference in cewp. Thanks for your input.

Comment: can you post the content of the txt file??

Answer (score 0):

Use tools like the IE developer toolbar and firebug in firefox to see what's going on and tweak the CSS.

Comment: @Eric: Yes sir, i have done that and I don't see anything unusual. No error is given. The 1st image appears without any caption. 2nd and 3rd image appears with captions but they dont match. 4th image dont even appear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure custom CSS is loading after the core.css.

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site! Just a note that we prefer posts here to have more detail, e.g. help the OP to understand why your suggestion will fix the problem.

Comment: How exactly i can dictate that?